# Pytorch, backprop and composite models

Tags: pytorch

Just a quick check for a question I have.

I want to build a model that generates its output based on two models `F` and `G` like so.

`y = G(F(x))`

where x is of course the input, and y the output.

However, first I want to update the weights of the `F(x)` and then later update the weights of both `F` and `G` based on the value of `y`.

I understand that pytorch offers a way to specify your own `backprop` method.. but since my "method" seems to build out of basic components, could it be that I can do this with a standard solution?

My thoughts would be that I need separate optimizer/loss for the `F` and `G` objects. But in addition to that, also some update functionality for the composite model `G(F())`. Can anyone confirm this as well?

Answer (score 1):

If as you suggest, the optimizers and losses for `F` and `G` can be separated, then I don't think that it will be necessary to implement any different update functionalities since you can specify the set of parameters for each optimizer, *e.g.*

```
optimizer_F = optim.SGD(F.parameters(),...)
optimizer_G = optim.SGD(G.parameters(),...)
```

then when you call `optimizer_F.step()` it will only update the parameters of `F` and similarly `optimizer_G.step()` will only update the parameters of `G`.